# Phonegap & Javascript -- Dynamic Resizing of Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I'm working on Android right now in Phonegap/Cordova and no matter what I do, I can't get a certain div to resize properly. It gets populated with a bunch of child-nodes in my Javascript and unless I hardcode the div to some ridiculous height, some of those get hidden. The weird thing is, when I set an "alert();" either before or after this...

```
var newheight=entlist.length*200;
newheight+=200;
document.getElementById('container').style.height=newheight+'px';
```

...it will show up properly. Also, "entlist" is a list of all the entries that get turned into child-nodes of 'container.' The idea is to make 'container' as tall as it needs to be to fit all those, plus a bit of a buffer, just in case, at least until I get it working and see what it looks like.

The fact that it appears properly with the alert made me think that the div simply needed to be redrawn. As such, I've tried...

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
document.getElementById('container').removeChild(div);
```

...and this, adding to the height every time a child is added...

```
var cH = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("container").style.height = (cH+150)+"px";
```

...setting 'container's height to "auto", and finally...

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<p>test</p>';
```

So, I've tried everything I could find on the subject. If someone could help me figure this out, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: What CSS is being applied to `#container`?

Comment: padding:0; margin:0; border:0;

Comment: Anything else?  Like with a `div` selector?

Comment: Nothing else. It gets hit with an appendChild for each entry in the list, but that's all.

Comment: Try giving it `display: block` just to be sure?  If there's any way you can reproduce this in Chrome/jsfiddle, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. I tried making a VERY condensed and simplified version of my code on JSFiddle, but it looks like it's working properly. It must be something going on in Phonegap, then?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! The div was inside of an iScroll wrapper and I didn't realize that there was even an option to refresh it. I just added one line to make it into...

```
var newheight=entlist.length*200;
newheight+=200;
document.getElementById('container').style.height=newheight+'px';
myScroll.refresh();
```

...and it worked like a charm. :)